# Mixin not used when null json is passed

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

Here is the code example:

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .addMixIn(MyClass.class, MyClassMixin.class);

        // calls constructor in the MyClass, all good valid object
        objectMapper.readValue("[\"test\"]", MyClass.class);

        // doesn't call constructor in the MyClass, doesn't fail either, returns `null`
        objectMapper.readValue(" null", MyClass.class);

        // calls constructor, checks that empty is not allowed and fails
        objectMapper.readValue("[]", MyClass.class);
    }

    static class MyClass {
        private Collection<String> items;

        public MyClass(Collection<String> items) {
            if (items == null)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot be null");
            if (items.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot be empty");
            this.items = items;
        }
    }

    static class MyClassMixin {
        private Collection<String> items;

        @JsonCreator
        public MyClassMixin(Collection<String> items) { }
    }
}
```

In the 2nd call, the returned value is null and the constructor isn't called. This circumvents the validation put inside the constructor.

The reason why I find this confusing is that I explicitly want object `MyClass` to be created and not `Collection<String>` or `String[]` which I understand could result in `null`.

Is there a way to ensure object `MyClass` is created using the constructor?